# alternative to using SDL_SetColorKey in SDL 1.2

Tags: c++, sdl, emscripten, color-key

I am currently porting a game written in C++ and SDL to the web using Emscripten. The problem is that I'm using legacy SDL instead of SDL2, which means that there are several functions I am using that are not compatible with Emscripten. Once such function is SDL_SetColorKey, which I would normally use to set a color key so that I can use sprite sheets. I am wondering if there is an alternative to SDL_SetColorKey in legacy SDL, something that would allow me to make the background of an image translucent without using SDL_SetColorKey.

Comment: Last time I've checked emscripten had SDL1.2, SDL2 support had to be compiled manually. But maybe things have changed since then. Anyway, SDL2 still have SDL_SetColorKey, so what exactly is your problem? If you want to use SDL_Texture for that functionality, you probably should convert colour key to alpha before feeding data into texture.

Comment: My problem is that the entire project was written in SDL 1.2, which means that if I want to use SDL_SetColorKey with Emscripten I need to port it over to SDL2. I was just wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/library_sdl.js doesn't look like SDL2 to me ('version' says 1.3, but I don't see anything higher than 1.2, no textures etc.). Have you tried emscripten's bundled SDL? If you're asking if there is a 100% compatible function for textures - then the answer is no, this is why we don't have old API implemented on top of SDL2 (it've been in 1.3, but it was dropped in 2).

Comment: This is the problem, emscripten's bundled SDL does not support SDL_SetColorKey. SDL2 emscripten does support it, but it would be a timesaver to skip porting to SDL2 alltogether. I'm not trying to find a compatible function for textures, just trying to find some way to make the background of an image translucent without using SDL_SetColorKey in SDL 1.2.

Comment: Ok, found `'SDL_SetColorKey is a no-op for performance reasons'`, but I think I lost your point here - are you trying to implement it on top of SDL2 or on whatever-subset-of-sdl1.2-emscripten-have-built-in (sorry)? If latter, you're quite out of options - convert surface to alpha and use ordinary blit. For SDL2 it might be possible to use this directly, with minimal porting on video mode setting (creating window manually instead of SetVideoMode, etc.), but it might increase asm.js size significantly, and dramatically reduce rendering performance (perf tests required, can't say how much).

Comment: Alright, I'm going to bite the bullet and port the project to SDL2. Hopefully there won't be a performance disaster.